# Why dd reads from output device?

Tags: dd

While `dd`ing a CentOS 7 x86_64 DVD image to a USB drive (sdb), I monitored the progress with `iostat`.

It kept alternating between mostly writing to the USB drive:

```
Device:            tps    kB_read/s    kB_wrtn/s    kB_read    kB_wrtn
sda              18,00       380,00        28,00        380         28
sdb              79,00        16,00      9000,00         16       9000
```

And reading from it hard disk and USB drive simultaneously:

```
Device:            tps    kB_read/s    kB_wrtn/s    kB_read    kB_wrtn
sda              53,00      5180,00         0,00       5180          0
sdb            1329,00      5316,00         0,00       5316          0
```

There was nothing else going on in the machine and, when `dd` stopped, the disks became idle.

Is it some sort of internal checksumming process in `dd`?

Anything inherent to USB drives' drivers in Linux 3.16.0?

Comment: Could you please provide the exact command being typed?

Comment: I looked at the source code for dd and there was nothing obvious. There is no checksumming occurring.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered a similar situation when secure-wiping an external (USB 2.0) hard disk: long periods of reads followed by a few seconds of high throughput writes, when I expected 100% writes. I used pv to show me an overall write speed (see command below) and I was getting an average of 10MB/s, in bursts of 14MB/s for ~10 seconds followed by a few kB/s. My iostat output looked very much like yours.

It turned out that the issue was my **much-too-small dd block size** (512 bytes). I suspect that what's happening is that the kernel was reading blocks into its 1k-per-block buffers so that dd can overwrite 512 bytes at a time, which then got flushed. I'm not a kernel expert so that' just a guess.

I can say that **pumping up my dd block size to 72K made a huge difference**. I am now seeing >40MB/s sustained writes. This is pretty close to the theoretical maximum that USB 2.0 can provide (480Kb/s, not counting USB overhead) and also pretty close to the maximum sustained write speed that this 10 year old disk can achieve (something like 55MB/s), so I'm satisfied that this is more or less bare-metal speed.

Here's the command I'm using to wipe the drive:

```
openssl enc -aes-256-ctr -pass \
pass:"$(dd if=/dev/urandom bs=128 count=1 2>/dev/null | base64)" \
-nosalt </dev/zero \
| pv -bartpes 160041885696 -B 128K \
| dd bs=72K count=2170707 of=/dev/sdf iflag=fullblock
```

Lines 1-3 pipe /dev/zero through AES-256-CTR encryption, using a password generated from /dev/urandom. So it's a stream of cryptographically random garbage.

Line 4 shows progress, given the 160GB drive's byte count and using a transfer buffer size in pv of 128KiB.

Line 5 uses a block size that I picked using a calculator, trying to find the largest multiple of 512 that was a factor of the total # of bytes of the drive. iflag=fullblock makes dd read repeatedly into its buffer until it has 1 full block before writing.